# Winforms .NET 4.5 app is crashing on a new machine

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.5, chilkat

On my development machine I have VS2010 and VS2012, developed an application using VS2012 using .NET 4.5 and Chilkat component for .NET 4 and platform target is x32 things are working fine on development machine.

Now when I moved this app on the Windows 7 Home Basic 32bit Virtual Machine application is crashing, after investigation found that when the app is trying to run the chilkat component it is failing but don't know what the hell is wrong because I am coping the 32bit dll along with the app in the bin folder but still complaining something else. Please help.

This is the error I am getting.

> Problem signature:   Problem Event Name:  CLR20r3   Problem Signature
>   01:   testing.exe   Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0   Problem Signature
>   03:   512e7778   Problem Signature 04:    Testing   Problem Signature
>   05:   1.0.0.0   Problem Signature 06: 512e7778   Problem Signature 07:    4
>   Problem Signature 08: e   Problem Signature
>   09:   System.IO.FileNotFoundException   OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.2
>   Locale ID:    1033   Additional Information 1:    0a9e   Additional
>   Information 2:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789   Additional
>   Information 3:    0a9e   Additional Information
>   4:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our
>   privacy statement offline:   C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Chilkat .NET assembly is a mixed-mode assembly, meaning that the internal implementation is written in C++ and compiles to native code.

If I'm not wrong, it is created using Visual Studio 2010 (using VC++). That's why, the Microsoft VC++ 2010 runtime library need to be present on the **target** computer.

There is no problem with the  2.0/3.5 .Net Frameworks because every windows OS computer already has the related VC++ runtimes already installed.

Could you try to install following VC++ packages from Microsoft? you can easy find download links on MS site, by your self..

- x86 Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package
- x64 Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package

If the 2010 packages dont work please try 2008 packages :

- x86 Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package
- x64 Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package